# Changing Default value of a Gravity Form drop down depending on which Wordpress menu item you click on

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have one menu in Wordpress with two links that go to the same page.  The links are named differently and I want to be able to change the default dropdown value in my gravity form to match which link they clicked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my answer.  In Gravity Forms for your dropdown you will have a value.  I found that as long as the value was one word it was easy to get it to be the default.  Make sure show values is checked if you want it to be required.  Then go over to the Advanced tab check the "Allow field to be populated dynamically" box and then for the parameter name enter a variable.  I used default_value.  In your wordpress Menu add a new menu item and for the name all you need is some html.  `<a href="contact-us/?default_value=contactUs">Contact Us</a>`  where the default_value is equal to the value of the dropdown item you wish to be default.